Why Power of a signal of amplitude $A$ is $A^2$
MATLAB YouTube Understanding Power Spectral Density and the Power Spectrum says Power P of frequency k  is $A^2 / 2$ .
$$ P = \frac {A^2}{2}$$

Is this correct? Because it looks $P = A^2$.

And the formula to calculate the sound decibels from the amplitude A and the power P also indicates $P = A^2$.
$dB = 10 * log_{10}(P) = 20 * log_{10}(A)$


It's only a square wave of amplitude $A$ that has power $A^2$.  Do you know why, if you apply a DC voltage of $V$ volts to a resistor of $R$ ohms, that the power dissipated by the resistor is $$ P = \frac{V^2}{R} $$ ?

The scaling for a sinusoid is specific to how a sinusoid is defined, leading to the definition of the one-sided PSD. The instantaneous and average powers of a signal have specific definitions, for which you don't need to use a PSD to calculate.

The term "power" is used for a bunch of different concepts and the interpretation depends on the context. Squaring a signal (either in time or frequency) will give a you metric of "signal power" which may or may not be related to the "physical power". Example if you have a voltage signal $v[n]$ over an ideal resistor, $R$ then you can estimate the instantaneous physical power as $p[n] = \frac{v^2[n]}{R}$. However if you have the same signal over an ideal capacitor, the power is completely unrelated to the voltage since $p[n] = 0$.
The first example explicitly calculates the power of a single sine wave. A sine wave of amplitude $A$ has a power of $A^2/2$. That's just a basic function of a sine wave and h as nothing to do with the DFT at all. If the sine wave happens to be at a basis frequency, $k_0$ of the DFT, the DFT coefficients will be $|X[k]| = A\cdot N/2 \forall k = \pm k_0, 0 \text{    else}$
In the case of a general signal the PSD is determined through the square of the DFT magnitude but the exact scaling is also context dependent.

And the formula to calculate the sound decibels from the amplitude A and the power P also indicates $P=A^2$

Sound pressure level has very little to do with physical acoustic power. It may be related to sound field intensity but that depends on the properties of the sound field. Do not equate Sound Pressure Level with physical power. They are very different things.

I'll add a simple and intuitive explanation that augments the good details Hilmar has provided:
Power is energy over unit time. Energy is the magnitude squared of the signal (in signal processing it is simply that regardless of possible scaling), so the total energy is the area under the curve  (the integral) of the waveform squared. If we divide that by unit time we get power and for a sinusoid specifically with peak amplitude $A$ that result approaches $A^2/2$.  (as time approaches infinity since it will it will be a cyclical result in the shorter time intervals, and exactly that over every integer half cycle of the sine wave). Thus the average power for a sine wave is $A^2/2$. Similarly the average power for a square wave would be $A^2$.
This becomes intuitive when you review a simple plot of a sine wave and sine wave squared: Here in this example I have  $x(t) = A\sin(\omega t)$ such that $A=4$, and once squared the result goes cyclically between $0$ and $16$, the average value is half of that as 8.  (And note if we took the square root of that we get the "rms" as root-mean-square, or the square root of the mean of the squared waveform..... as fred harris would say "ta-da!").

As far as coefficients of the Fourier Series $A_k$, we need to be careful to specify if the Fourier Series is given as a sum of sinusoids (one-sided; no negative frequencies), or given as a sum of exponentials (two-side; positive and negative frequencies). The two are related according to Euler's formulas relating real sines and cosines to pairs of complex exponentials:
$$A\cos(\omega t) = 0.5Ae^{j\omega t}+ 0.5Ae^{-j\omega t}$$
$$A\sin(\omega t) = -0.5Aje^{j\omega t}+ 0.5Aje^{-j\omega t}$$
So if the Fourier Series for a single frequency tone at $\omega=2\pi f$ is given as a one sided Fourier Series, we would have just one real sinusoidal component with the power $A^2/2$ consistent with what was introduced above. However if the Fourier Series for a single frequency tone is given as a two sided Fourier Series, we would have two complex exponential components (a positive frequency component as $0.5Ae^{j\omega t}$ and a negative frequency component as $0.5Ae^{-j\omega t}$), each therefore with a power of $A^2/4$. When you add the two to get the total power in the waveform, the result will be $A^2/2$. So nothing is lost, just clarity on how it is being represented.
Side note: The function $0.5Ae^{j\omega t}$ is complex and thus when squared to determine power and energy it is actually a complex conjugate product consistent with "magnitude squared": $(0.5Ae^{j\omega t})(0.5Ae^{-j\omega t}) = 0.25A^2$
